# App Keeps Crashing

Tags: java, android, crash

My app i've created using android studio keeps crashing and I don't know why. Its a weather app and i'm following google's developing android app course, here's the logcat:

```
    07-20 18:19:45.740  16410-16434/com.alexander.sunshine E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.alexander.android.sunshine.app
07-20 18:19:45.748  16410-16434/com.alexander.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.alexander.sunshine, PID: 16410
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
            at com.alexander.sunshine.app.FetchWeatherTask.addLocation(FetchWeatherTask.java:109)
            at com.alexander.sunshine.app.FetchWeatherTask.getWeatherDataFromJson(FetchWeatherTask.java:214)
            at com.alexander.sunshine.app.FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(FetchWeatherTask.java:414)
            at com.alexander.sunshine.app.FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(FetchWeatherTask.java:34)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

And here's the FetchWeatherTask.java:

```
package com.alexander.sunshine.app;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.alexander.sunshine.R;
import com.alexander.sunshine.app.data.WeatherContract;
import com.alexander.sunshine.app.data.WeatherContract.WeatherEntry;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;

public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
    private final Context mContext;

    public FetchWeatherTask(Context context, ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter) {
        mContext = context;
        mForecastAdapter = forecastAdapter;
    }

    private boolean DEBUG = true;

    /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
     * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
     */
    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
        Date date = new Date(time);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
        return format.format(date).toString();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */
    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        // Data is fetched in Celsius by default.
        // If user prefers to see in Fahrenheit, convert the values here.
        // We do this rather than fetching in Fahrenheit so that the user can
        // change this option without us having to re-fetch the data once
        // we start storing the values in a database.
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        String unitType = sharedPrefs.getString(
                mContext.getString(R.string.pref_units_key),
                mContext.getString(R.string.pref_units_metric));

        if (unitType.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.pref_units_imperial))) {
            high = (high * 1.8) + 32;
            low = (low * 1.8) + 32;
        } else if (!unitType.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.pref_units_metric))) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Unit type not found: " + unitType);
        }

        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to handle insertion of a new location in the weather database.
     *
     * @param locationSetting The location string used to request updates from the server.
     * @param cityName A human-readable city name, e.g "Mountain View"
     * @param lat the latitude of the city
     * @param lon the longitude of the city
     * @return the row ID of the added location.
     */
    long addLocation(String locationSetting, String cityName, double lat, double lon) {
        long locationId;

        // First, check if the location with this city name exists in the db
        Cursor locationCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                WeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID},
                WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING + " = ?",
                new String[]{locationSetting},
                null);

        if (locationCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int locationIdIndex = locationCursor.getColumnIndex(WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID);
            locationId = locationCursor.getLong(locationIdIndex);
        } else {
            // Now that the content provider is set up, inserting rows of data is pretty simple.
            // First create a ContentValues object to hold the data you want to insert.
            ContentValues locationValues = new ContentValues();

            // Then add the data, along with the corresponding name of the data type,
            // so the content provider knows what kind of value is being inserted.
            locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_CITY_NAME, cityName);
            locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING, locationSetting);
            locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT, lat);
            locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG, lon);

            // Finally, insert location data into the database.
            Uri insertedUri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(
                    WeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    locationValues
            );

            // The resulting URI contains the ID for the row.  Extract the locationId from the Uri.
            locationId = ContentUris.parseId(insertedUri);
        }

        locationCursor.close();
        // Wait, that worked?  Yes!
        return locationId;
    }

    /*
        Students: This code will allow the FetchWeatherTask to continue to return the strings that
        the UX expects so that we can continue to test the application even once we begin using
        the database.
     */
    String[] convertContentValuesToUXFormat(Vector<ContentValues> cvv) {
        // return strings to keep UI functional for now
        String[] resultStrs = new String[cvv.size()];
        for ( int i = 0; i < cvv.size(); i++ ) {
            ContentValues weatherValues = cvv.elementAt(i);
            String highAndLow = formatHighLows(
                    weatherValues.getAsDouble(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP),
                    weatherValues.getAsDouble(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP));
            resultStrs[i] = getReadableDateString(
                    weatherValues.getAsLong(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE)) +
                    " - " + weatherValues.getAsString(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC) +
                    " - " + highAndLow;
        }
        return resultStrs;
    }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr,
                                            String locationSetting)
            throws JSONException {

        // Now we have a String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format.
        // Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
        // into an Object hierarchy for us.

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.

        // Location information
        final String OWM_CITY = "city";
        final String OWM_CITY_NAME = "name";
        final String OWM_COORD = "coord";

        // Location coordinate
        final String OWM_LATITUDE = "lat";
        final String OWM_LONGITUDE = "lon";

        // Weather information.  Each day's forecast info is an element of the "list" array.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";

        final String OWM_PRESSURE = "pressure";
        final String OWM_HUMIDITY = "humidity";
        final String OWM_WINDSPEED = "speed";
        final String OWM_WIND_DIRECTION = "deg";

        // All temperatures are children of the "temp" object.
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";

        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";
        final String OWM_WEATHER_ID = "id";

        try {
            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            JSONObject cityJson = forecastJson.getJSONObject(OWM_CITY);
            String cityName = cityJson.getString(OWM_CITY_NAME);

            JSONObject cityCoord = cityJson.getJSONObject(OWM_COORD);
            double cityLatitude = cityCoord.getDouble(OWM_LATITUDE);
            double cityLongitude = cityCoord.getDouble(OWM_LONGITUDE);

            long locationId = addLocation(locationSetting, cityName, cityLatitude, cityLongitude);

            // Insert the new weather information into the database
            Vector<ContentValues> cVVector = new Vector<ContentValues>(weatherArray.length());

            // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
            // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
            // properly.

            // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
            // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
            // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

            // now we work exclusively in UTC
            dayTime = new Time();

            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // These are the values that will be collected.
                long dateTime;
                double pressure;
                int humidity;
                double windSpeed;
                double windDirection;

                double high;
                double low;

                String description;
                int weatherId;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);

                pressure = dayForecast.getDouble(OWM_PRESSURE);
                humidity = dayForecast.getInt(OWM_HUMIDITY);
                windSpeed = dayForecast.getDouble(OWM_WINDSPEED);
                windDirection = dayForecast.getDouble(OWM_WIND_DIRECTION);

                // Description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                // That element also contains a weather code.
                JSONObject weatherObject =
                        dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);
                weatherId = weatherObject.getInt(OWM_WEATHER_ID);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                ContentValues weatherValues = new ContentValues();

                weatherValues.put(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LOC_KEY, locationId);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE, dateTime);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_HUMIDITY, humidity);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_PRESSURE, pressure);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WIND_SPEED, windSpeed);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DEGREES, windDirection);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP, high);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP, low);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC, description);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WEATHER_ID, weatherId);

                cVVector.add(weatherValues);
            }

            // add to database
            if ( cVVector.size() > 0 ) {
                ContentValues[] cvArray = new ContentValues[cVVector.size()];
                cVVector.toArray(cvArray);
                mContext.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(WeatherEntry.CONTENT_URI, cvArray);
            }

            // Sort order:  Ascending, by date.
            String sortOrder = WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " ASC";
            Uri weatherForLocationUri = WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate(
                    locationSetting, System.currentTimeMillis());

            // Students: Uncomment the next lines to display what what you stored in the bulkInsert
            Cursor cur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(weatherForLocationUri,
                    null, null, null, sortOrder);

            cVVector = new Vector<ContentValues>(cur.getCount());
            if ( cur.moveToFirst() ) {
                do {
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues(cur, cv);
                    cVVector.add(cv);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FetchWeatherTask Complete. " + cVVector.size() + " Inserted");

            String[] resultStrs = convertContentValuesToUXFormat(cVVector);
            return resultStrs;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        String locationQuery = params[0];

        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int numDays = 14;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, locationQuery);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // This will only happen if there was an error getting or parsing the forecast.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if (result != null && mForecastAdapter != null) {
            mForecastAdapter.clear();
            for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
                mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
            // New data is back from the server.  Hooray!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the stack trace says, you're trying to call `moveToFirst()` on a null reference. `locationCursor` is the only object you're calling that method on, so it must be null.

The docs for [query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)) say that it can return null, so you'll should null check that object, and you should also check your invocation of `query()` to try to understand why it's returning null.

Comment: I'm only new to this so can you show me how I can fix this

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, in your addLocation method, the locationCursor you get by calling `Cursor locationCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(...)` is null, which causes the crash when you call `locationCursor.moveToFirst()` just after that.

I suggest to check out [this problem's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080540/what-causes-androids-contentresolver-query-to-return-null). The problem might be that the query is empty.

In any case, you should always check whether the Cursor is null before you apply methods to it, and deal with that case somehow by alerting the user.

The method could look like this:

```
    long addLocation(String locationSetting, String cityName, double lat, double lon) {
    long locationId;

    // First, check if the location with this city name exists in the db
    Cursor locationCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID},
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING + " = ?",
            new String[]{locationSetting},
            null);

    if (locationCursor != null) {
        if (locationCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int locationIdIndex = locationCursor.getColumnIndex(WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID);
            locationId = locationCursor.getLong(locationIdIndex);
            locationCursor.close();
            return locationId;
        }
    }
    // Now that the content provider is set up, inserting rows of data is pretty simple.
    // First create a ContentValues object to hold the data you want to insert.
    ContentValues locationValues = new ContentValues();

    // Then add the data, along with the corresponding name of the data type,
    // so the content provider knows what kind of value is being inserted.
    locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_CITY_NAME, cityName);
    locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING, locationSetting);
    locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT, lat);
    locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG, lon);

    // Finally, insert location data into the database.
    Uri insertedUri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            locationValues
    );

    // The resulting URI contains the ID for the row.  Extract the locationId from the Uri.
    locationId = ContentUris.parseId(insertedUri);
    locationCursor.close();
    // Wait, that worked?  Yes!
    return locationId;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, I looked at the accepted answer

Comment: Just after the statement `Cursor locationCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(...)`, change your if-statement to check if locationCursor is null: instead of `if (locationCursor.moveToFirst()) {...} else {...}` write `if (locationCursor != null) {if(locationCursor.moveToFirst()) {...}} else {...}`

Comment: In fact, the else-block should be executed also when only `locationCursor.moveToFirst()` resturns false. For example, add `return locationId;` in the end of the first `{...}`-block, remove the `else` and just leave the second `{...}`-block as it is, behind the if-statement.

Comment: Still crashing but different error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.alexander.android.sunshine.app/location`

Comment: Since the URL is not recognized, there is an additional problem.  Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226473/how-to-fix-content-provider-url-not-found-in-android) helps.

Comment: I fixed it the url i used did not match my package so I changed it, It works now

Comment: glad I could help you